# Using AVAudioPlayer from class outside ViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

New to iOS and `Objective-C`,  have been struggling to figure this out. I have a class that holds a strong reference to an `AVAudioPlayer` object and defines a method to play an mp3 depending on the parameter 'tag', which belongs to a `UIButton`. In my view controller I have a method that uses this class to play a sound when a button is pressed. But when I run the simulator and press the button, the mp3 is not being played. When I don't use the other class and make the `AVAudioPlayer` belong to my `ViewController`, initialize it in `viewDidLoad`, and call play right in the `IBAction` method, it works fine. I checked that the files are available to my project and that they are being referenced correctly in the code.

I looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180258/must-avaudioplayer-be-instantiated-from-a-viewcontroller-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490952/playing-sound-on-button-av-audio-player-returning-nil-string-parameter), neither solved my problem. Here's my code

GuitarTuner.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface GuitarTuner : NSObject
- (void) play: (NSUInteger)tag;
@end
```

GuitarTuner.m

```
#import "GuitarTuner.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface GuitarTuner()
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@end

@implementation GuitarTuner

- (void) play:(NSUInteger)tag
{
    NSString *note;
    switch (tag) {
        case 0:
            note = @"Low-E";
            break;
        case 1:
            note = @"A";
            break;
        case 2:
            note = @"D";
            break;
        case 3:
            note = @"G";
            break;
        case 4:
            note = @"B";
            break;
        case 5:
            note = @"Hi-E";
            break;
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:note ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GuitarTuner.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) GuitarTuner *tuner;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (GuitarTuner *) tuner
{
    if (!_tuner) return [[GuitarTuner alloc] init];
    return _tuner;
}

- (IBAction)noteButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    [self.tuner play:button.tag];
}


@end
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Silly mistake! Just didn't properly initialize GuitarTuner property in the getter in ViewController -- should be `_tuner = [[GuitarTuner alloc] init]` Answer below works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialise `AVAudioPlayer` like this

```
NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                     initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:note withExtension:@"mp3"] error:&error];
```

UPDATE:

You give yourself your answer:

> When I don't use the other class and make the AVAudioPlayer belong to
>   my ViewController, initialize it in viewDidLoad, and call play right
>   in the IBAction method, it works fine.

Try to alloc `tuner` in viewDidLoad or create from your class `GuitarTuner` a singleton and from there everything will be much easier.

Also comment this:

```
- (GuitarTuner *) tuner
{
    if (!_tuner) return [[GuitarTuner alloc] init];
    return _tuner;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Alloc'ing tuner in viewDidLoad did the trick, but now I'm really confused. Why did that work?...